# Android Image Crop: Output x and Output y always 160 px

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-image, android-crop

When I choose a photo from the gallery it always turns 160 pixels in width and height. But the width and height I want is 640.

The code I use is below.

```
 private void photoChooser(){

    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", true );
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX",4);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY",4);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX",640);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY",640);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", 
    Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_IMAGE);

}
```

the code I use to select photos;

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
        try{
            final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if(extras != null){
                Bitmap bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                lastImage = bitmap;
                roundedBitmapDrawable2 = 
RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(this.getResources(),bitmap);
                roundedBitmapDrawable2.setCircular(true);
                imgProfile.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable2);

            }
        }catch (Throwable ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

3 days I've been trying for this, but what I did not do. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: There is no requirement for any Android device to support those `Intent` extras. Please use [an image-cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).

Comment: @CommonsWare thask for your answer. I try this.